# Android : 5.0 : WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, webview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to make my webview compatible with android 5.0 for the upload file purposes.My build target is API19 4.4.2 . I have download 5.0 sdk and it dependencies.  I am getting an error WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams cannot be resolved to a type

**I found this code on Stackoverflow.**

```
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                        WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                        WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                    // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                    if(mFilePathCallback != null) {
                        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                    mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                    // Set up the take picture intent
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        // Create the File where the photo should go
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // Error occurred while creating the File
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                        }

                        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        } else {
                            takePictureIntent = null;
                        }
                    }

                    // Set up the intent to get an existing image
                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                    // Set up the intents for the Intent chooser
                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if(takePictureIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }

                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                    return true;
                }
        });
```

**Issue** 
[image]

Comment: I didnt find much answers regarding this on stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams` is new to API Level 21, as is the `onShowFileChooser()` method.

So, you need to set your `compileSdkVersion` (a.k.a., "build target" in Eclipse) to 21, otherwise those symbols will not be recognized.

Comment: Done Thanks for the help